# Is there any way to display a function call graph?

Tags: language-agnostic, ide, graph, stack

While browsing through source code in my IDE I'll sometimes wish I could see a call stack/s or function call graph from a particular point in the code (while the program isn't running) to help me understand the sequence of events better.

An example of the functionality I'd like to see is:
I click a function called 'sendNotificationEmail'
And a 'stack' of functions is displayed (owner is to the right):

```
sendNotificationEmail->EmergencyNotificator->CheckIfServersOnFire->UpdateThread->Main
```

My question is: Can any ides/plugins/or otherwise display such information, and if not - why?

This question isn't IDE or language specific.

Comment: You have at least specify the programming language you are using. We are programmers, not a team of Californian Psychics. It all depends on the language. Go parse assembler or C++ and generate a call graph.

Comment: I'm just interested to see if solutions to this problem exist, and the various solutions. You don't need to be psychic to answer.

Comment: Some IDE's and tools (see answer below), works across multiple languages.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad / tool rec. Fix an IDE or CLI and let's talk ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does tend to be IDE / language-specific. IntelliJ and Eclipse both have Call Hierarchies available for Java methods, which lets you look at callers and callees for a given method. Visual Studio offers similar facilities for MS languages.

For less mainstream languages, you might need to swallow some [Rich Programmer Food](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/06/rich-programmer-food.html) if the available tools aren't up to it.

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is a tool that can take your code and create call graphs, UML diagrams, class hierarchies, etc...  It works on C++, Java, among others.  It produces output in HTML and Latex, and others I think.  It operates on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

For the most part, it is a standalone program.  However, you can use it within the [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) IDE to do some basic previews of Doxygen output.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 can do this (I assume newer versions as well):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3zaa390(VS.80).aspx

The results are displayed as a tree in a separate view/window.